# Change Tik Tok bio automatically

Tags: web

Is there any way to automatically change and update a Tik Tok bio with each new follower? Maybe a counter that displays the number of followers. What would be used to implement this? I guess JavaScript wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the TikTok API to get number of followers and then write a script that triggers once the follower count increases to change the bio. [Here's the information from TikTok's dev site](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/tiktok-api-v1-user-info?enter_method=left_navigation)

You should be able to get the bio from the API calls too

Comment: Thank u! I didn't know there was smt. like this.

Comment: no problem! there should be all the information you need on that site, and usually for connecting to various apps and stuff there's always an API you can use